# Rendering action of another controller if validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Almost on each page of my application, I have a partial with the form, where I can create an Offer. For this, I have an `offers_controller` with a proper `create` action:

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    offer = Offer.new(offer_params)
    if offer.save
      redirect_to confirmation_offer_path
    else
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path, alert: 'Something went wrong.')
    end
  end

  private

  def offer_params
    params.permit(:company, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :subject, :message)
  end

end
```

What I need is to display the error messages if validation fails. As this form is located on every page, I don't know how to render an appropriate action. If I had only one page with this form, the controller would look like this:

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @offer = Offer.new
  end

  def create
    @offer = Offer.new(offer_params)
    if @offer.save
      redirect_to confirmation_offer_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def offer_params
    params.require(:offer).permit(:company, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :subject, :message)
  end

end
```

So, how can I render an action to show the error messages? Thanks ahead.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4591182/456673

Answer (score 2):

You can use flash messages:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash.html

Then, in your application layout file, you can handle this, for example:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %> alert-dismissable fade in"><%= value %>
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: But I need the data to stay in the form after a failed validation. That is why I need to render an action.

Comment: If you set flash messages, and then do a render, you'll need to use `flash.now[:error] = "Something was wrong"` instead. `flash[:x]` is set after redirect (next request), while flash.now is set in THIS action, for example when using render.